# How can I disable spellcheck in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, text-editor

I'm using CKEditor 4.7.
my CKEditor keep checking spells like this picture.
[image]

and it makes this error.

[image]
this error makes my browser is getting slow...

I tried scayt setting in config such as 'scayt_autoStartup = false;',
'data_enable_grammarly="false";'.
but it doesn't work.

I just want to remove Grammarly check and this error.

Answer (score 0):

Disable or remove Grammarly extension.